# Find object of class detoured function

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering

I have detoured a class method using `CDetours` via a dll injection (yes I'm studying reverse engineering) `void MyClass::SetData( D3DXVECTOR3& data )`, and on the real application everything works fine, the function is detoured and I see the debug messages (a console output).

Now to the real problem is that i'm trying to make this function a call, if it was a global function instead I'd do:

```
typedef void (*SetDataFunc)(D3DXVECTOR3&); //for global functions __cdecl is ok
SetDataFunc SetDataRev = (SetDataFunc)0x00428FD0; //just an example address

then call it:

D3DXVECTOR3 data(0,0,0);
SetDataRev(data);
```

and everything would work fine again, my problem is that even knowing the address of `MyClass::SetData` and using the method above to call it (it indeed is called), but the `MyClass` object created would stay the same, because tbh the call itself doesn't makes sense since you're not calling it from an object.

E.g

```
MyClass myobj;
myobj.SetData( data ); //ok any members that 'SetData' changes will be changed.

SetDataRevForClass( data ); //not ok, nothing on 'myobj' changed
```

How can I call the class method "from" the `myobj` on my dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the calling convention. You'll need to examine how exactly the member functions are represented in your intercepted DLL. At the c++ side, the above declaration and assignment are wrong, the type of the member function is: void (MyClass::*)(D3DXVECTOR3&). How this gets translated depends on the calling convention, but in any case a pointer to object of MyClass must be passed at invocation time.